# 'Aliyah an Isur 'Aseh? Even today?

Tags: halacha, aliya-laaretz, golus-exile, tractate-brachot, babylonian-exile

The Gemara [(Bab. Ber. 24b*)](http://www.dafyomi.org/index.php?masechta=brachos&daf=24b&go=Go) quotes R' Yehudah as saying that anyone who leaves Bavel to go to Israel violates an Isur 'Aseh (a violation of the parameters of a positive commandment), because the Navi says [(Jer. 27:22)](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt1127.htm#22), "They shall be brought to Babylon and there they shall [remain] until the day I redeem them."

Four(-ish) part question:

1. Why does the [Navi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nevi%27im#The_Prophets) have the power to enact a Biblical(-style?) law?
2. According to R' Yehudah, why was this still in effect in the times of the Talmud?  After all, the Babylonian exile had ended and the Second Temple had been built by that time (and used for several hundred years, desecrated, re-dedicated, used for about 200 years more, and then destroyed again).  Although R' Abba (and most Jews) lived in Bavel, this was the period of the *Roman* exile, which has lasted to today.

   a. Did the Isur 'Aseh apply for all generations?

   b. Does the Isur 'Aseh apply specifically because they went back to Bavel?

   c. (If b.) Does the Isur 'Aseh apply only in Bavel?
3. (Closely related to 2a) According to R' Yehudah, would this apply even today?  (Same sub-questions - does it apply only to Jews living in Iraq, or to everyone, and why?)
4. What about leaving Bavel to go somewhere else?

*Sorry, I'm behind on my [Daf-Yomi Challenge](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1325/5) questions!^

^(Others should feel free to participate!)

---

BTW, this should *not* get into Hashkafic considerations or political discussions with regard to positions held by Natorei Karta and/or other groups, although this may be the basis for their position. This question is purely exploring the Halachic reasoning of R' Yehudah as recorded in the Gemara.

Comment: I noticed there are a couple of tags for exile, but none for redemption. Ironic.

Comment: Related to your first question: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/16046/what-is-the-level-of-divrei-kabbalah

Comment: @SethJ Maybe something here http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1334/759

Comment: Maybe people pasken like R' Zeira who didnt want to pasken like  R'Yehuda in shabbas daf 41a

Comment: @ShmuelBrin, I'm not sure he would. I think there it can easily be argued that we were redeemed by G-d via 'Ezra. Question #2 is more centered on the notion that I would think that that redemption would have effectively ended the ban (and if it did, I wonder why it would be reinstated) - and then the sub-questions that spring from there. I'm not sure what you mean by Hillel. And of course there are many examples of people traveling back and forth in Mishnaic and Talmudic times, too.

Comment: FWIW, R' Chaim Kanievsky recently told two young men from Lakewood that it's a positive commandment to move to Israel today. http://baltimorejewishlife.com/m/news/article.php?SECTION_ID=1&ARTICLE_ID=57814

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. From the words of the [Malbim](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=6686&st=&pgnum=212&hilite=) on Shas it would be an extention of the Torah law of keeping oneself out of danger.
2. Again from the same Malbim: Because the "chain" must not be broken until they conclude Talmud Bavli.

   a. According to the [Rambam](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?mfid=94098&rid=14948), yes; according to Rashi (quoted in Lechem Mishne), only if there are Yeshivos.

   b. According to (above) Malbim, yes; according to Rashi, only because the Yeshivos were in Bavel (so you could say yes).

   c. According to Rambam, yes;
3. According to Rambam, yes;
   (does it apply only to Jews living in Iraq? According to Rambam, yes because of Possuk, according to Rashi, no because there are no Yeshivos there now)
4. According to Rambam, not allowed; according to Rashi, when there were Yeshivos in Bavel it is not allowed.

Answer (score 3):

The Maharatz Chajes discusses this in [Maamar Torat Nevi'im, ch. 7](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_22101_318.pdf):

> וכן ניחא נמי ליישב הא דלא מנו מוני המצות מה שאמרו חז"ל (כתובות קי"א ע"א) העולה מבבל לא"י עובר בעשה שנאמר בבלה יובאו ושמה יהיו עד יום פקדי אותם, והיינו דמצוה זאת היא היפך ממצות התורה שנצטוינו בשעת מתן תורה לרשת את הארץ ולהאחז בה, ואם לא היינו חוטאים היתה עדיין א"י מוחזקת אצלנו, וע"כ מצוה זאת הוא כשאר תקנות וגזירות שקבלו עליהם אחר גלות מהארץ, עי' ב"ב (ס' ע"ב) ועי' רמב"ן בתוספותיו לס' המצות מ"ע ד' דחשב במנין המצות לרשת את הארץ והרב בעל מגלת אסתר דחה דברי הרמב"ן דאם מצוה זאת נוהגת לדורות איך אמר ירמיה בבלה יובאו עד יום פקדי אותם והרי אין נביא רשאי לחדש על ד"ת מכ"ש לסתור ע"ש, ואני אומר ולטעמיך גם לשיטתו לא יתכן דנהי דמ"ע דירושת א"י אינה לדורות מ"מ איך חדשו הנביאים באיסור שלא לצאת מבבל לא"י, והרי אין הנביא רשאי לחדש וע"כ דלא באו הנביאים לעשות ולחדש מצות התורה, רק הוא כשאר גזירות שעשו ישראל בימי הגלות וקבלו עליהם הצומות וגזרו שלא לסוד ולכייד ביתו, עי' ס"פ חזקת הבתים, כן גזרו שלא לעלות לא"י בלתי אם ישלח ה' מלאכו לפנינו לפדות אותנו מן הגלות המר והנמהר, ואף דבתחילה היתה ירושת א"י לחובה עלינו מ"מ רשות ביד ב"ד לאסור את הדבר שהיתה מצוה עלינו... ועיין רמב"ם ספ"ה מהלכות מלכים דלא הביא הדין רק בעולה מבבל לשאר ארצות ולא הביא לשון הש"ס מבבל לא"י, ואולי כיון דמתנגד למצות התורה אסור להם אפילו להחמיר ובפרט לעשות מן המצוה איסור

The prohibition is like all the other decrees and fasts accepted by the Jews in the times of exile - it is purely Rabbinic. The Rambam holds that since there is a Mitzvah to go to Eretz Yisroel at all times, the Chachamim cannot forbid going to Eretz Yisroel, only other lands, so only going to other lands is forbidden.

Comment: Perhaps you should consider translating and/or summarizing this quote.

Comment: Yes, please translate/summarize.