# Gathering of the tribes: contradiction between Rambam and mefarshim

Tags: messiah, eretz-yisrael, messianic-redemption, zionism

It is a well known principle that **Moshiach** will gather all the people that are in exile, and bring them into Eretz Yisrael ([Yeshayahu 11:12](https://www.sefaria.org/Isaiah.11.12?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en); [Mishneh Torah Hilchos Melachim uMilchamot 11:1][1]](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Kings_and_Wars.11.1?lang=en&with=all&lang2=en)).

Rabbi Yisachar Shlomo Teichtal in his work "Em Habanim Smeicha" (p. 47) writes:

> The essential point is that **Hashem is waiting for us to take the initiative**, to desire and long for the return to Eretz Yisrael. **He does not want us to wait for Him to bring us there**. that is to say, when we, of our own volition, truly and with all our strength, desire and strive to return to the Land, then G-d will bring our work to an succesful end. (emphasis mine)

According to Rav Teichtal, G-d does not want us to wait until exile ends, but wants us to return to Zion instead.

There is a similair statement that can be found in the commentary of the [Haamek Davar on Devarim 30:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.30.3?lang=bi&with=Haamek%20Davar&lang2=en). It reads:

> And gather you from all of the nations: **After the main exile returns
> from the nations**, the Lord will return to gather the small pockets
> among the nations where the Lord scattered you. Likewise did Ramban
> write 1 in his commentary on Song of Songs (8:12), "you may have the
> thousand, O Solomon" - **that at first, there will be a partial
> gathering of the exiles with the permission of the governments.** And
> afterwards, the Lord will bring back His hand a second time, as it is
> written, "and He will return and gather you." (emphasis mine)

Also, the [Malbim](https://www.sefaria.org/Micah.4.8?lang=bi&with=Malbim&lang2=en) says that the exiled will begin to return to Zion.

---

> He will build the Sanctuary and gather in the dispersed of Israel.

There seems to be a contradiction in these two statements.

My question is: How does this fit with the famous statement of the Rambam, namely that all of the above is done by Moshiach? Are there any mefarshim (commentaries on this Rambam or else) that discusses this contradiction? On the one hand, Hashem wants us to return (according to the above mentioned sources), but according to the Rambam and many explanations from a "Satmar-perspective" we are meant to wait until Moshiach takes us "from the four cornes of the world", as we pray daily.

Comment: relevant: [Is it Halachically forbidden to go to Israel?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/68493/11501)

Comment: Did you check whether R' Teichtal cites any sources to back up his claim? IIRC, he cites many sources in Em Habanim Smeicha, generally.

Comment: He mentions for example Teh. 132:14. Furthermore he says "If we arise to Zion, we will rectify the souls of the Children of Israel who died in sanctification of G-ds name, because they caused us to return to our forefathers".

Comment: Another thing is that the Malbim on Micah 4:8 writes: The re-establishment of the Jews as a "strong fortress" will happen in 3 parts: 1) [...] Those who were exiled from Yehuda and Binyamin will begin to return to Tzion [...]. However, this does not fit with the famous Rambam that says that it is Moschiach who will gather the exiled.

Comment: This post reads primarily as an argument or an analysis of a dispute and not as a request for information. The sentence ending in a question mark looks more like compliance-decoration than like the focus of the post. I recommend significant revision to pare this down to a question and any information needed to support that question.

Comment: I think I might start this as a question but for now, at what point did we go from being kicked out and door slammed shut to "Hashem wants us to return"? I think the reason some comments asked for sources is because this is not a clear topic in general so heavy use of sources would be very prudent

Comment: @RabbiKaii excellent question.

Comment: @Shmuel reading what Rabbi Yisachar Shlomo Teichtal wrote in your quote a second time, it is almost saying that Hashem doesn't want us back until we ourselves want it. So perhaps more sources to show that He wants us back, or rather perhaps the question is wrong. He always wants us, but that's the root of it all: we have to want Him too, He's never going to force us...

Comment: I don't really see the contradiction between the Mishneh Torah and mefarshim you quote. The Mishneh Torah, doesn't say that the Moshiach will gather in _all_ of Israel (in the sense that there will be none, or few, in the Land before he comes). In fact, saying "_He will_ ... _gather in **the dispersed of** Israel_ (**נדחי** ישראל)", suggests that there could be those of Israel who aren't dispersed (i.e. who are already in the Land). The mefarshim you quote don't say that _all_ Jews will return before the Moshiach comes. So, he could gather the small pockets still scattered among the nations.

Comment: @TamirEvan: This might be a possible answer. Are there any mefarshim that discusses the interpretation of נדחי ישראל to mean what you write?

Comment: @Shmuel "_Are there any mefarshim that discusses the interpretation of נדחי ישראל to mean what you write?_" Not that I know of, and it's not my main point. Nevertheless, to me it's logical: "The dispersed of Israel" is a sub-group of "[all of] Israel" (otherwise why not simply say "_he will_ ... _gather in_ [all of] _Israel_"). Being a sub-group _suggests_ it is not the entire main group. So, it could be all of Israel will be dispersed when Moshiach comes (as in a "Satmar-perspective"), or it could be only small pockets scattered among the nations will remain by then (R. Teichtal et al.).

Answer (score -1):

The answer to these contradictory statements: The future is not decided yet.

Certain incidents that are definitively meant to occur are decided. For example, Moshiach coming is a definite future event. If you lived 4000 years ago, then the Exodus from Egypt was a definite future event.

But there can be a billion different ways that Moshiach can come. He can come wearing a suit or while eating a sandwich etc. He can come while Biden is President or while Trump us President.
The " how do we get there " part is not decided and depends on us; because of free choice.

There could have been a billion different ways the exodus could have happened. It wasnt necessary that it should have happened after a lot of suffering. The suffering could have come in the form of anguish at living outside the land of Canaan.

Same way , the ingathering of the exiles is bound to happen but how it will unfold  is not set in stone. This is one of the reasons why even when prophets prophesied, they couldn't clearly see every detail of future events. This is because the lesser motions that help realise something big like the destruction of the temple for example, were not set in stone.

But it is upto you personally to put in motion a certain chain of events. You can make Aliyah with the kavvana that you are beginning the ingathering of the exiles or you can stay where you are and pray for the ingathering of the exiles. Either way, it will happen. We just dont know if it will be through you or someone else.

Everything I said here is from the Rambam more or less.

Comment: This does by no means answer my question as to how to resolve the contradictions by the mefarshim.

Comment: @Shmuel I do think that this is also an answer to your question. We do not really know what is going to happen. That should be the starting point of the discussion. We will understand the prophecies clearly only once they have happened - as the Rambam himself has said clearly (don't remember where?). So "contradictions" between the mefarshim may just be their understandings of how certain parts of the mesorah read best, not requirements.

Comment: @Shmuel I am replying in the most polite tone and so please dont misunderstand me.  It will make sense if you keep thinking about what I said for a few days and then it will dawn on you. Usually, these topics are not normally processed by the human mind immediately.