# What level of obligation is of kriat shema al hamita?

Tags: halacha, minhag, sleep, shema

What is the level of obligation for krias shema al hamita (the recitation of Shema before going to bed)? Is it a mitzvah deoraisa, mitzvah derabanan, is it a minhag avoseinu byadeinu? Maybe it's something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [Brachos 4b,](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot_4b.27) Rabbi Yehoshua ben Levi says it's a mitzvah to read the shema again.
Rav Yossi brings a passuk from Tehillim ([Psalm 4:5](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.4b.27?lang=bi&p2=Psalms.4.5&lang2=bi)) as proof.
It seems that one has an obligation to recite the shema before going to sleep, and it seems to me to be a d'rabbanan.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/16046