# Divrei Kabbalah in Maimonides' Usage

Tags: rambam, navi-prophets, ketuvim

Rambam in the Laws of Fast Days (4: 7) writes that verses are recited from "Divrei Kabbalah" and from "Kitvei Kodesh" (holy writings).

> וּפְסוּקִים מִדִּבְרֵי קַבָּלָה וּמִכִּתְבֵי הַקֹּדֶשׁ

What do these two terms refer to?

Does the former perhaps connote Prophets, while the latter connotes Writings?

Comment: Have you investigated this yourself at all? What have you found?

Comment: See also http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/16046

Comment: "Does the former perhaps connote Prophets, while the latter connotes Writings?" Yes

Comment: http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?mfid=28790&rid=2761

Comment: @DoubleAA someone once told me that he thought he saw someone who claimed that divrei kabbalah refers specifically to prophets as opposed to ketuvim.

Comment: @Matt excellent. What/where is this book?

Comment: @wfb very good. He says like me. :) Why not make that comment an answer?

Comment: @DoubleAA If all I had was this Rambam I assume divrei kabbala referred specifically to Prophets. The only other reference to it I found in the MT referred to Malachi; part of Prophets. From the provided link the Yeshuos Meshicho agrees to the inference. And cites a Maseches Sofrim which I havent looked up yet.

Comment: The Rambam says (מדע פרק א' הלכה יב'):   ודברי קבלה בכלל תורה שבכתב הן ופירושן בכלל תורה שבעל פה

Comment: @Mefaresh how does that answer the question?

Comment: @mevaqesh did I answer the question? Comments are not answers

Comment: @Mefaresh just making sure

Comment: @msh210 that's the translation used in  the touger edition

Comment: @ShamanSTK Did you mean to ping me? I don't know what you're referring to by the word "that".

Comment: @msh210 nope, meant @ wfb. Trying to use the stack exchange app and failing due to my fat fingers.

Comment: @wfb See above.

Comment: I think @ShamanSTK had someone else in mind

Comment: Related: "[Definition of the Written Law](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/57639/1368)".

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the opposite is true. In the Rambams litterateur דברי קבלה usually refers to the Torah Shebeal Pe (קיבלו במסורת) (although the Rambam view is that Halachot learned from נ''ך is in the status of Drabanan, so he might have referd to them as Divri Kabala as well) while כתבי קודש refers to Torah Shebechtav.

Comment: You are correct. Divrei kabbalah in this context is referring to Torah sh'bal Peh. The oral transmission of proper text as transmitted through masorah all the way to the teachings of the Gaonim.